# Crontab spawning multiple instances of task instead of a single instance

Tags: python, bash, cron, multiple-instances

I have a python script which needs to run every 5 minutes. I am calling this script via a `bash` file named `activate.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
../../env/bin/python3 ./run.py
```

Then to run this task every 5 minutes, I have a `crontab job` configured as such:

```
*/5 * * * * cd /var/www/usa/api/BackgroundTasks && /bin/bash ./activate.sh
```

I have literally the same setup running on 3 different servers 2 of which work just fine and activate the task only once. The one on the USA server however spawns multiple instances of `run.py`. This went so far that it nearly filled up the entire memory causing performance issues.

Here is the `app.py` code but I don't think the issue is there, I think the issue is with `cron` itself:

```
import time, sys, os, datetime
try:
    sys.path.append("../")

    from Flabstraction.Flabstraction import Pysqlalchemy, MailingService
    from Flabstraction.constants import constants_dict

    from AutomatedReports import schedules_builder_2
    from DeleteOldJobs import delete_old_jobs
    from StallTimers import stop_timers

    constants_selector = "LOCAL"
    path_to_self = os.getcwd()
    selectors = ['/au/','/eu/','/nz/','/usa/','/demo/']
    for sel in selectors:
        if sel in path_to_self:
            constants_selector = sel.upper().replace('/', '')
            break
    constants = constants_dict[constants_selector]

    mail = MailingService()
    sql = Pysqlalchemy('mysql+pymysql', constants["mysql_user"], constants["mysql_pw"], constants["server_ip"], constants["mysql_db"])

    file = open('./background.log', 'w')
    file.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " : running started. \n")

    if constants_selector in ["LOCAL", "US"]:
        schedules_builder_2(sql, constants["timezone"], constants_selector, mail, constants)    
    if constants_selector in ["AU", "NZ", "EU"]:
        delete_old_jobs(sql, constants["timezone"])

    stop_timers(sql, constants["timezone"], constants["_instance_id"])

    file.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " : running stapped. \n")
    file.close()

    except Exception as e:
        file = open("./background.log", "w")
        file.write("Error occured: ", e)
        file.close()
        raise e
```

Any idea how to resolve this and why it would be happening on only 1 of 3 servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I went through my code in detail and found that one of my constructors was giving a warning message which essentially froze the script while waiting for an input by the user.

The way I resolved this was by using the `getcwd()` function imported from `os` in order to check which folder is calling the python script where this happened.

Having:

```
├── BackgroundTasks
│   ├── AutomatedReports.py
│   ├── DeleteOldJobs.py
│   ├── StallProjects.py
│   ├── StallTimers.py
│   ├── activate.sh
│   ├── background.log
│   └── run.py
├── Config
│   ├── Config.py
│   ├── common.py
│   ├── connect.py
│   ├── constants.py
├── app.py
```

I was executing `run.py` from my `activate.sh` file. When I run the application I call the `app.py`.

Using the `getcwd()` function, I was able to check if I call the script from `BackgroundTasks` and therefore add a case in my `connect.py` script to ignore the user input when invoked from that folder.